# Count swaps needed to order a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I wrote this code since I'm going through the hackerrank challenges, however, it takes way too long to run.
Its function is described on the title, but just to clear it up, we need to count the minimum amount of swaps needed to order a set of ascending integers.

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    count = 0
    correct = [(x+1) for x in range(len(arr))]
    while arr != correct:
        for i in arr:
            if i != arr.index(i)+1:
                a = i
                b = arr[i-1]
                arr[i-1] = a
                arr[arr.index(i)] = b
                count += 1
                break
    return count
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    res = minimumSwaps(arr)
    print(str(res))
```

Comment: That won't work on input `200 1 45` ---> `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: The input format should be:
1st Line: integer of the size of the array
2nd Line: the array itself

Comment: I mentioned about "2nd Line: the array itself" - it throws an error. Besides, the result of statement `n = int(input())` is not used anywhere in your code

Comment: Oh, sorry again, the second line should be n space-separated integers that form the array. So the complete input should look something like: 4 (new line) 4 2 1 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have time to really look at the code well or do a full review, but what did stick out to me was the repeated calls to `arr.index(i)`. That's an expensive call that will require, in the worst case, a full iteration of `arr` *each time*.

At the very least, that call should be done once then cached. Really though, that information is already available to you without searching if you use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def minimum_swaps(arr):
    count = 0
    correct = [(x+1) for x in range(len(arr))]
    while arr != correct:
        for i, x in enumerate(arr):  # I changed what was i to x, then made i the index
            if x != i+1:
                a = x
                b = arr[x-1]
                arr[x-1] = a
                arr[i] = b
                count += 1
                break

    return count
```

I also renamed some variables. `i` is an awful name for an element that *isn't* itself an index, and the function name should be in snake_case instead.

Comment: Wow, this just changed the run time from 200 seconds to 0.1628 seconds (literally). Thanks a lot man

Comment: @AndréFradinho Ya, no problem. Be aware of what the functions you're using are doing behind the scenes, and be wary of excessive use of any function that is repeatedly searching through a list or other sequence.